# Filtering through results of pandas groupby count columns

Tags: python

I have used the code below to group my Pandas Dataframe based on Hourly Rate, and Hourly Rate Quartile.

```
e = df.groupby(['Hourly Rate Quartile', 'Hourly Rate']).size().reset_index(name='Count')

print(e)
```

This prints out my three columns.

I now want to filter through these results and print only those that have Count>1.

I have tried in many different ways:

```
if e.loc[e['Count']] > 1:
         print (e)
```

Before that, I also used:

```
if e['Count'] > 1:
         print (e)
```

In both cases, I get a `ValueError: The truth value of a DataFrame is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().`

I tried a For loop as well.

```
for i in e['Count']:
         if i>1:
              print(i)
```

Which gives me the right results but I would like to get all three columns.

So, when I try:

```
for i in e['Count']:
         if i>1:
              print(e)
```

It prints everything again.

This is the last thing I've tried:

```
for i in e:
    if i['Count']>1:
              print(i)
```

Which gives me this error: `string indices must be integers.`

Do you guys have any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
In [1]: df = pd.DataFrame({'c1': list("aacd"), 'c2': list("bbcd")})

In [2]: df
Out[2]:
  c1 c2
0  a  b
1  a  b
2  c  c
3  d  d

In [3]: series = df.groupby(['c1', 'c2']).size()

In[4]: series
Out[4]:
c1  c2
a   b     2
c   c     1
d   d     1
dtype: int64

In [5]: series[series > 1]
Out[5]:
c1  c2
a   b     2
dtype: int64
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame([['A', 5],
                   ['A', 4.],
                   ['B', 1],
                   ['B', 2]], columns=['col1', 'col2'])

df = pd.merge(df,
              (df
               .groupby('col1')
               .count()
               .reset_index()
               .rename(columns={'col2': 'count'})),
              how='left',
              on='col1')

xx = df.loc[df['count'] > 1]
```

Comment: Hello! Thank you for taking the time to answer my question. I think I am missing something in your solution. My first two columns exist, and I create the third column (the 'Count' column) using the groupby.count().reset_index() function. In your example the one you are going to use as 'Count' is created straight by you. Am I understanding correctly?

Comment: yes, I do count the items, create count column and use it to filter the data.